# Build two different apk for same project expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'am developing mobile application using expo.

I need to build two different apk for dev/testing purpose and for prod (difference between apps - client server endpoints).

Any  suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In android, these distributions are called build flavors. I don't know anything about React Native or expo, but from a quick google search, it seems that you might want to use https://docs.expo.io/distribution/release-channels/

Comment: Even creating different apk with different release-channel, can't install both the apps on same device, newly installed apk will be replaced to the old one.

Comment: This is android specific. You can't have two apps that have the same package name. If you want to have both apps installed at the same time, then you should name the packages differently: com.supercool.app.dev and com.supercool.app.prod . In this way, you'll be able to have both apps installed at the same time

Comment: I changed package name and built apk, now i can keep both the app on same device. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

[Environment variables in Expo](https://docs.expo.io/guides/environment-variables/).Using different .env file for different purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i need to standalone apk,
there are some difference between dev and prod, some features are still in dev for testing, i cant take that to prod and need to test dev apk at the same time prod apk need to be installed in mobile.

Comment: Install two versions dev and prod on the same device?

Comment: Exactly same project-two app (diff version)-same device, sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: I changed package name and built apk, now i can keep both the app on same device. Thank you!!